# How to make a unique url for dynamically created web page in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm work on my project in Asp.net (C#), I've created a page called UserProfile.aspx, in this page the user fills its details, In addition i've a main.aspx file which is the main page of the website:

In my Main.aspx file:

```
<input type="button" id="createProfile" runat="server" />
```

In my Main.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createProfile.ServerClick += new EventHandler(createProfile_Click);
}

protected void createProfile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/UserProfile.aspx");
}
```

Now, when the user clicks on the `createProfile` button, the `UserProfile` page is opened and all right.

Now i want to make a specific `UserProfile` page for each user, i mean i want to make the url specific for each user.

I will try to explain myself as better as i can: When every user opens the `UserProfile` page, the url in the browser's address bar is `.../UserProfile.aspx` = same for each user, and i want it to be different for each user, for example: for user called "John" it will be `.../JohnUserProfile.aspx` or something like that.

I will give an example so that it will be clear:

**For example** in this web site "StackOverflow", for each question that asked, a web page is created and named according that question, in addition the address (url) of this web page is consists of parts of the title of the question, for example: the question "Dynamically created html controls" has a url ".../dynamically-created-html-controls...", And more: the user can save this web page (or the address of this page) in the browser's bookmarks and access this page later.

So as shown from the above example, what i want is that for each user it will be a specific url for his `UserProfile` page, so the user can save the page as a bookmark in the browser and access the page later without go through the Main.aspx page and click the createProfile button etc.

Excuse me for the long explanation, I'll try to make it short, My question is how to create unique `UserProfile` page for each user (when having the general template for that page = UserProfile.aspx) and how to save this page or its address? in asp.net C#?

I mean, just redirect the user to the "UserProfile" page and load his data from the database to that page isn't what i want, because it doesn't create new `UserProfile` page for this specific user.

I hope you understood me.

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: you use a query string value. Ie .../UserProfile.aspx?user=John or even better an id that represents a unique id in a users database table

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/7997729/d-rotnemer` is a good example

Comment: Usually you site will have a main page with json macros (or aspx).  The main page will take parameters and pass to the child pages.  A list of dynamic controls can be a parameter that is that can be added.